# MATLAB: Growing an array and logical indexing

Tags: matlab

I create the following array in MATLAB:

[image]

Now I find which elements of `x` are greater than 4:

[image]

So far so good. Now I create an array of length 8:

[image]

And now I execute this command:

[image]

I am very confused as to what just happened. What is this command doing? Why is `z` now an array of length 15?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to accomplish with the command `z(y)=1`?

You will get some strange behaviour since `z` and `y` have different sizes. You should check the [array indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html) documentation on MATLAB to better understand what is happening and how array indexing works.

Because you provided your code as an image, i will use a different x matrix to explain what is happening. Following your steps, we have:

```
rng('default'); % set random number generator, so you will get the same matrix as me
x=randi(10,[2 8]); % create random matrix

> x =
> 
>      9     2     7     3    10     2    10     9
>     10    10     1     6    10    10     5     2
```

Find elements greater than 4:
    y=x>4 % creates y

```
> y =
> 
>   2×8 logical array
> 
>    1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1    
>    1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
```

Create array of length 8 (?). (Lets skip this step)

```
...
```

Assign:

```
z(y)=1

> z =
> 
>      1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
```

What is happening here? MATLAB will use the array `y` as the indices to the newly created variable `z`. To better understand the difference between the indices 0 and 1 of the `y` array and the assignment `=1` to the `z` array, lets just change the value to 2:

```
z(y)=2

> z =
> 
>      2     2     0     2     2     0     0     2     2     2     0     2     2     2     2
```

Now it should be easier to understand. First, because `z` does not exist in the workspace (or, in your case, because the number of elements in `z` is smaller than the number of elemnts in `y`), MATLAB will create this variable. The size of the variable is the same as the size of the y array with nonzero elements:

```
y(:)'

> ans =
> 
>   1×16 logical array
> 
>    1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
```

Notice `y` is a logical array. With that in mind, what the assignment `z(y)=2` does is to assign `2` to every `true` element of the array `y`. Because the last element is 0, MATLAB will disregard this element and will not include it in the array. Think of it as if MATLAB would do:

```
z(logical([1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1  0]))=2
```

The last comment is how MATLAB changes the 2×8 y array to a 1×16 array.
Check this other [documentation on array indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html), to better understand *Indexing with a Single Index*. When you call all elements of array as in y(:), MATLAB uses the **linear index** instead of the **array index**. We call it row-wise operation, because MATLAB will consider each column as an 1d array and concatenate them altogether, as explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) , with the visual aid:

[image]